# iPhone:How to change the background color of 'TTTabStrip' Tabbar in Three20 lib?

Tags: iphone, three20

I have added facebook's Three20 static library successfully into my project and able to view scrollview tabbar called 'TTTabStrip' which has defined in TTCatlog project. I want to now change the background color of the tabbar as Tabbar is always showing like silvertint color. How do i change TTTabStrip tabbar background color. I tried almost all the scenarios but not able to be success on this.
If anyone knows about Three20 projects and changing the color etc. please share your ideas to me or provide me the link where i can have solution.

UPDATE: In-fact, i should look for changing different Tabbar style (for ex: UIBarStyleBlackOpaque) instead of background color.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

To change the style of the TTTabStrip I did the following:

1) Create a custom style, i.e. a class extending from TTDefaultStyleSheet

2) Override the tabStrib method. For example, I used a greyish gradient as background, with this code:

```
- (TTStyle*)tabStrip {
UIColor* border = RGBCOLOR(130, 130, 130);
return
[TTBevelBorderStyle styleWithColor:[UIColor whiteColor] width:1.0f next:
[TTLinearGradientFillStyle styleWithColor1:RGBCOLOR(130, 130, 130) color2:RGBCOLOR(67, 67, 67) next:
 [TTFourBorderStyle styleWithTop:border right:nil bottom:nil left:nil width:1 next:nil]]];}
```

3) Register your custom style, using `setGlobalStyleSheet`

4) Watch the result and start swearing because the overflow arrows now don't match anymore :)

5) Override the `- (TTStyle*)tabOverflowLeft` and `- (TTStyle*)tabOverflowRight` in your custom style in a way your images, crafted to match the background, were returned.

If you guys devise a better method, let me know :)

Comment: That's probably the only way to tackle it right now. Next question ... how does one change the colors of the tab text and the rounded rectangle selection? Answer: override tabRound: as well.